# JSR 303 validation for collection of beans in java?

Tags: java, bean-validation

I am trying to validate collection of beans and it looks as below,

```
 public class Employee{
    @NotNull(message = "The name parameter is mandatory")
    @NotEmpty(message = "Please provide a valid value for name parameter")
    protected String name;
    protected String address;
    protected String phone;

//getters and setters

}


public class Employees{
    @NotNull(message = "The town parameter is mandatory")
    @Valid
    protected List<Employee> employees;
    //getters and setters
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/addEmployees", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
public String addEmployees(
        @Valid @RequestBody Employees employees, BindingResult result){
                if(result.hasErrors){
                    List<ObjectError> errors = result.getAllErrors();
                    for (ObjectError error : errors) {
                        System.out.println(error.getDefaultMessage());
                    }
                }
                //business logic
}
```

Request:

```
{
    "employees":[
        {
            "name":"John",
            "address":"New York",
            "phone":"12312123"
        },
        {
            "name":"Scott",
            "address":"New Jersey",
            "phone":"12312123"
        }
    ]
}
```

Requirement is for above request it should log validating errors for each Employee in employees collection to BindingResult.
Hence if name is not present in request, it should print
"The name parameter is mandatory".

Comment: So what is the problem? You get an error? Different message than the one expected? not validation error at all?  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Not validated at all. If @RequestBody is instance of Employee and not a collection (i.e Employees) it will get validated.

Comment: Can you clarify the version of spring and add the Spring MVC configuration you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Adding this as an answer for the time being:

Most probably, you haven't initialised the validator. In your spring MVC spring configuration file, add then following:

```
<bean id="validator"
class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>
```

This is explained in the [spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-beanvalidation-spring).